# Calculate duration of gap in 24 hour time period loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work out the duration of any gaps in a 24 hour time period that exist across all periods. In particular when the gap is between the start of the first boundary and the end of the last.

The example boundaries are as follows. The gap is from 23:00 - 01:00

```
const b1 = {
    id: 1,
    start: '01:00',
    end: '06:00',
};
const b2 = {
    id: 2,
    start: '06:00',
    end: '17:00',
};
const b3 = {
    id: 3,
    start: '17:00',
    end: '23:00',
};
```

Or the gap could be from 06:00 - 08:00, but there are overlaps of 17:00 - 20:00 and 24:00 - 23:00.

```
const b1 = {
    id: 1,
    start: '23:00',
    end: '06:00',
};
const b2 = {
    id: 2,
    start: '08:00',
    end: '20:00',
};
const b3 = {
    id: 3,
    start: '17:00',
    end: '24:00',
};
```

I have this rudimentary loop which is working out when the gap sits between the first item and the last, but not the last and the first.

```
const timeStringToNumber = (time24Hours) => {
    const hoursMinutes = time24Hours.split(/[.:]/);
    const hours = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10);
    const minutes = hoursMinutes[1] ? parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10) : 0;
    return hours + minutes / 60;
};

const boundaries = [b1, b2, b3]
const errors = [];

boundaries.forEach((boundary, index, array) => {
    const a = timeStringToNumber(boundary.start);
    const b = timeStringToNumber(boundary.end);
    let c, d

    if (index + 1 === array.length) {
        c = timeStringToNumber(array[0].start);
        d = timeStringToNumber(array[0].end);
    } else {
        c = timeStringToNumber(array[index + 1].start);
        d = timeStringToNumber(array[index + 1].end);
    }

    if (b < c) {
        errors.push({
            start: b,
            end: c,
        })
    }
    
})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with overlaps, since they are not gaps.

Comment: @MattEllen thanks for the response. I don't want to do anything with the overlaps. But the change to adding 24 to the "c" value is causing a error to be pushed: { start: 24, end: 23 }. The overlap for 17:00 - 20:00 doesn't generate an error - which is what is required.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. I will take another look

Comment: Isn't `{start:24, end:23}` an error? that's a gap of 23 hours.

Comment: Or to put it another way in your first example 23:00 to 01:00 would be an overlap of 22 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is 23 is greater than 1.

I'm going to assume the wrap around means that a day has passed, so what you can do is when you detect a wrap around (i.e. `index+1 === array.length`) you can add 24 to `c` and `d`, unless `b` is midnight, then don't increase `c`.

```js
/*const b1 = {
    id: 1,
    start: '01:00',
    end: '06:00',
};
const b2 = {
    id: 2,
    start: '06:00',
    end: '17:00',
};
const b3 = {
    id: 3,
    start: '17:00',
    end: '23:00',
};*/

const b1 = {
    id: 1,
    start: '23:00',
    end: '06:00',
};
const b2 = {
    id: 2,
    start: '08:00',
    end: '20:00',
};
const b3 = {
    id: 3,
    start: '17:00',
    end: '24:00',
};

const timeStringToNumber = (time24Hours) => {
    const hoursMinutes = time24Hours.split(/[.:]/);
    const hours = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10);
    const minutes = hoursMinutes[1] ? parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10) : 0;
    return hours + minutes / 60;
};

const boundaries = [b1, b2, b3]
const errors = [];

boundaries.forEach((boundary, index, array) => {
    const a = timeStringToNumber(boundary.start);
    const b = timeStringToNumber(boundary.end);
    let c, d

    if (index+1 === array.length) {
        c = timeStringToNumber(array[0].start);
        d = timeStringToNumber(array[0].end);
        if(b > c && c < d) {
            c += 24;
        }
    } else {
        c = timeStringToNumber(array[index + 1].start);
        d = timeStringToNumber(array[index + 1].end);
    }

    if (b < c) {
        c = c % 24;
        errors.push({
            start: b,
            end: c,
        })
    }
})

console.log(errors)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Matt. This fixes the initial conditions, but after working with it a bit more, I've identified some edge cases which will cause the gap to wrap the entire 24hrs, which is not wanted. Any suggestions?

Comment: @sansSpoon what are those edge cases?

Comment: I added another set of boundaries to the description. The gap is between 06:00-08:00 but there are overlaps of 17:00-20:00 and 23:00-24:00. As it stands that generates `[ { start: 6, end: 8 }, { start: 24, end: 23 } ]`

Comment: I've modified your answer that fixes the problem, the `the b != c` was still an issue. Thanks again for sticking with it.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you figure it out